# How to stop threads of tomcat which creating memory leak?

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, memory-leaks

We have installed java application on tomcat with linux server. 
When we shut down tomcat server I am getting following error messages in logs.

*created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [null]) and a value of type [org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentTermEnum] (value [org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentTermEnum@19a419a4]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.*

Can any one help me 
How I stop these threads?
And
How prevent these error should not appear again?

Please reply as early as possible we are facing this issue in our production which cause slowing our web application.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat complains about a thread not being stopped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707254/tomcat-complains-about-a-thread-not-being-stopped)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ThreadLocal & Memory Leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968803/threadlocal-memory-leak)